# NSTableView keyDown: and mouseDown:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I've been working on a menubar note-taking application for Mac. It is written in Objective-C and Cocoa, and I'm using BWToolkit with it. My problem is getting keyDown: and mouseDown: events in a BWTransparentTableView which is a subclass of NSTableView. I just can't get it to work. I've tried searching the Internet, and some places say that you must subclass NSTableView. I've tried that, but it still doesn't work. I am pretty new to Objective-C and Cocoa, and I may just be doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your subclassing attempt and what you're seeing wrong (beyond "can't get it to work", that is :-) ). It's easiest to start there.

Comment: I tried subclassing NSTableView in a class called MyTableView.The only thing that class does is override keyDown:, but keyDown: is never called. Is there any other way to get keyboard and mouse events in an NSTableView? What I'm really wanting is to allow items in the table view to be double-clicked to open them and be renamed when enter is pressed or when it is slowly double-clicked.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you believe requires overriding `keyDown:` and `mouseDown:`?

Comment: The documentation said that the double-click message isn't sent when the cell is editable. I searched and all I could find was that they had to be overridden to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Items in an `NSTableView` will automatically begin editing when they are slow double-clicked or when the Return key is pressed. Make sure that the table view, the cell and the array controller (if used) are marked as editable.

If you are not using an `NSArrayController`, make sure that your table view has a delegate and that it responds to `tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:`.

To handle a double click, you just need to set the `doubleAction` of the table view:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [tableView setTarget:self];
    [tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(doubleClickInTable:)];
}

- (void)doubleClickInTable:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger rowIndex = [sender selectedRow]; //Use selectedRowIndexes if you're supporting multiple selection
    //Handle the double click
}
```

Note that neither of these methods require you to subclass `NSTableView`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly. It's just that I read in the documentation that if a cell is editable, the doubleAction: isn't sent.